# Why TCP connection is broken too early?

Tags: python, timeout, freebsd, tcp

I run the following Python program on FreeBSD:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket

host = ''
port = 9000

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
serversocket.bind((host, port))
serversocket.listen(5)

while True:
    sock, address = serversocket.accept()
    print("Connected ", address)
    sock.settimeout(3600)
    data = sock.recv(4096)
    sock.close()
    print("Disconnected")
```

Then I connect to it with `telnet XXX 9000`. The connection is broken after 5 min and a few seconds. Why it is broken after 300 seconds (well actually 304 seconds) instead of 3600 seconds (which I set in the `settimeout` method)?!

I need to run my TCP connection for an extended period of time, but I found no way to do it, except of sending non-sense ping messages. Is there any other way?!

Comment: There are two ends of a socket; did the other side close it?

Comment: @FilipHaglund I think, it doesn't

Comment: Default timeout for telnet on windows seems to be an hour. Cannot find a value for BSD. Try using netcat (since that doesn't have a timeout by default) https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?nc

Comment: @FilipHaglund I run telnet from a Debian Linux machine, FreeBSD is only at the server

Comment: Still, give `nc` a try :) Lets us know if telnet is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the kernel to ping the connection with:

```
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPIDLE, 150)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPINTVL, 150)
```

solves the problem.

After such settings the connection does not break, as I need.